# How do I respond to clicks in editor mode?

Tags: unity, c#

It's working fine in run time but I wonder if there is a way to make it work also in editor mode ?
I tried to add to the top of the script :

```
[ExecuteAlways]
```

Because I want it to work on both run time and eidtor.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (plane.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            {
                GameObject cube = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn);

                cube.transform.position = hit.point;
                cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(50, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
```

I removed the code from the update and created for testing a public method :

This is in the mono script :

```
public void SpawnThroughPlane()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (plane.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            {
                GameObject cube = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn);

                cube.transform.position = hit.point;
                cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(50, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
```

Than created editor script :
The editor script is in Assets/Scripts/Editor

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjectsEditor : Editor
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(SpawnObjects))]
    private void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        SpawnObjects spawn = (SpawnObjects)target;

        Event e = Event.current;
        if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown)
        {
            spawn.SpawnThroughPlane();
        }
    }
}
```

But the editor script is not working at all I tried to add a break point in the editor script but it seems like the editor script is not active :

Even if I'm going back to the editor the break point is not working.

[image: Break point is not working and the script it self the editor script is not working at all even if it's in the Editor folder in the assets]

Comment: Is it really spawning a prefab you're having trouble with? Or is it detecting the mouse click?

Comment: The problem is that it's not working in editor mode.  it's working fine in run time.  I tried to create a editor script but it's not working either I can't even make a break point in the editor script.  I will update my question.

Comment: "it's not working" - always be more specific than this. Is the `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` condition satisfied? If not, say "How do I respond to clicks in editor mode?" If the condition is met and your code enters the `if` block, but something else goes wrong, describe that something else.

Answer (score 1):

As per Unity API documentation for the CustomEditor attribute ([here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomEditor.html)), `[CustomEditor]` must be put on the custom *editor class itself* (in this case, the class is `SpawnObjectsEditor`), and not on the `OnSceneGUI` method.

Try moving the attribute like this:

```csharp
[CustomEditor(typeof(SpawnObjects))]
public class SpawnObjectsEditor : Editor
{
    private void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```